# Automating multiple clicks on a button until a result appears

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

hello I want to do more than 5 times clcik on a button until I get a message but I do not want to do it in the traditional way that there is an angular shape JS

```
driver.findElement (By.linkText ("Examples")). click ();
driver.findElement (By.xpath ("// button [@ type = 'button']")). click ();
driver.findElement (By.xpath ("// button [@ type = 'button']")). click ();
driver.findElement (By.xpath ("// button [@ type = 'button']")). click ();
driver.findElement (By.xpath ("// button [@ type = 'button']")). click ();
driver.findElement (By.xpath ("// button [@ type = 'button']")). click ();
  driver.findElement (By.xpath ("// h1 [2]"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this one:

```
 driver.findElement(By.linkText("Examples")).click();
    while(true)
    {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("// button[@type='button']")).click();
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("// h1[2]")).isDisplayed(),"Message is not displayed");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

```
driver.findElement (By.linkText ("Examples")). click ();
while(true){
driver.findElement (By.xpath ("// button [@ type = 'button']")). click ();
int count=  driver.findElements (By.xpath ("// h1 [2]")).size();
if(count>0){
break;
}
}
```

Explanation of the code:
The while loop will always be continued. in every iteration we are clicking on the button and checking that whether the h1 element is available. if the element is found then the loop will be terminated.
To check the element status we have used driver.findelments method, this returns the list of web elements and we are taking the count.

try this code and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

THE PREVIOUS SOLUTION AND THIS APPLY

```
    WebElement buton = element(By.xpath("//button[@type='button']"));
    boolean isPresent = 
 isElementVisible(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/h1"));

    for (int i = 1; i > 0; ++i) {
        buton.click();
        System.out.println("Mensaje");

        if (isPresent == true) {
            System.out.println("Mensaje ");
            break;
        }

        isPresent = isElementVisible(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/h1"));
    }

}
```